# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your

Tags: mysql

string(10) "20,999,999" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '999,999' at line 11

I have a string I am trying to search for in my database and retrieve all values lower than the given number.

In my database, the field is a VARCHAR(45). It works perfectly fine with another field for square footage.

I have tried replicating it so that it is similar to the square footage solution I have, but to no avail.

```
    $sql = "SELECT address.address AS address, 
address.price AS price, 
county.county AS county,
type.type AS type,
address.idaddress AS idaddress, address.feet AS feet
FROM address
JOIN county
    ON address.county_idcounty = county.idcounty
JOIN type
    ON address.type_idtype = type.idtype
WHERE 1=1";

var_dump($_GET["prices"]);


if( isset($_GET["address"]) && !empty($_GET["address"]) ) {
    var_dump($_GET["address"]);
    $sql = $sql . " AND address.address LIKE '%" . $_GET["address"] . "%'";
}

if( isset($_GET["location"]) && !empty($_GET["location"]) ) {
    $sql = $sql . " AND county.idcounty =" . $_GET["location"];
}

if( isset($_GET["property"]) && !empty($_GET["property"]) ) {
    $sql = $sql .  " AND type.idtype =" . $_GET["property"];
}

if( isset($_GET["prices"]) && !empty($_GET["prices"]) ) {
    $sql = $sql .  " AND address.price <=" . $_GET["prices"];
}

if( isset($_GET["feet"]) && !empty($_GET["feet"]) ) {
    $sql = $sql .  " AND address.feet <=" . $_GET["feet"];
```

Feet is the square footage and it works perfectly fine... I would like to be able to search for all prices lower than 20,999,999.

If you need more information please let me know. I appreciate the help!

Comment: in a number data type should not be present  comma ..

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: I will use prepared statements afterwards:P Trying to get something working first for demo purposes. Thank you for the information though.

Comment: @scaisEdge The data type is a VARCHAR(45). I did not use an number data type. I will try to revert it to a type INT though and see if it works.

Comment: the if is not a number but a string this must be enclosed  in single quioet

Comment: @scaisEdge On second thought, it would be preferable to use a string. I would much rather prefer a horizontal scrollbar... but I do not what tool I can use for that. If you know, please inform me.

Comment: @scaisEdge I understand that you were referring to something else now. Could you show me what you mean by providing some code?

Comment: Uhh.. I do not know what is happening. But it works perfectly fine now... the bug is gone..? MAMP is something else...

Comment: **Stop coding right away and learn prepared statements**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you column price is a varchar  then the related  where must be enclosed  in single quote

```
  $sql = $sql .  " AND address.price <='" . $_GET["prices"] . "'";
```

anyway you should not use php var in SQL you are at risk for sql injection  (you should take a look for prepared statements and binding param)

Comment: Interesting... I tried this before but it did not work! Thanks again, much appreciated @scaisEdge

Comment: you have another error  ? ..  or the query work but yu have a not expected  result  ..  ??

Comment: Actually it works, my string for prices is giving me an unexpected error. Feet is the same varchar, but when I use that without the '" . ____ . "'"; it works perfectly fine lol! But nonetheless, I am not receiving an error for the prices so that problem itself is solved, just another issue that I have encountered after the fact.